# Convert Virtual Directory to Web Application in WiX

Tags: iis, deployment, wix

I am creating a new `WebSite` whenever Feature A or B is installed:

```
<Component Id="IIS.HelloWorld" Guid="6FA5EF90-C9D9-463C-9CC7-0410670AFBD1" Directory="TARGETDIR">
  <iis:WebSite Id="IIS.HelloWorld" Description="Hello World for Web" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
    <iis:WebAddress Id="HelloWorldAddress" IP="*" Port="8080"/>
  </iis:WebSite>
</Component>
```

The WebSite is pointed to the INSTALLDIR (Say C:\MyFiles). Below the INSTALLDIR, I have 2 additional folders: **Service** (C:\MyFiles\Service) and **Web** (C:\MyFiles\Web)

Since the WebSite is pointed to INSTALLDIR, all sub-directories (**Service** and **Web**) were automatically treated as Virtual Directories (?) -- I can see them linked via IIS Management Console and I can access them via my browser.

However, they need to be "converted" to Applications (done manually by right-clicking the Virtual Directory and selecting "Convert to Application) in order for them to work properly (they contain ASPX and ASMX files).

So I've added the following component to try to convert them to "Applications":

```
<Component Id="IIS.HelloWorld.WebSite.VirtualDirectory" Guid="GUID-44D1-48D9-BB3C-4B0126FB83E5" Directory="TARGETDIR">
  <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="IIS.HelloWorld.WebSite.VirtualDirectory" Alias="Service" Directory="INSTALLDIR.WebSite" WebSite="IIS.HelloWorld">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="IIS.HelloWorld.WebSite.VirtualDirectory" Name="Service"/>
  </iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>
```

But the Virtual Directories wasn't converted to "Applications"; they are still just virtual directories.

Question: How do I convert virtual directories to applications in WiX? Or what is the proper way to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was binding the wrong Virtual Directory Alias to the wrong Web Application Name.

This code works:

```
<Component Id="IIS.HelloWorld.WebSite.VirtualDirectory" Guid="GUID-44D1-48D9-BB3C-4B0126FB83E5" Directory="TARGETDIR">
  <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="IIS.HelloWorld.WebSite.VirtualDirectory" Alias="Web" Directory="INSTALLDIR.WebSite" WebSite="IIS.HelloWorld">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="IIS.HelloWorld.WebSite.VirtualDirectory" Name="Web"/>
  </iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>
```